# Risks of exposing .htaccess file

Tags: windows, php, apache, xampp

I have an Apache server on Windows 7 using XAMPP running php in cgi mode. One of the users can modify the .htaccess file to restrict the access to the webpage for some ip addresses and configure other settings. He cannot view the source of the php files stored in the server, and I don't want him to be able to do it.

Since php is running in cgi mode, adding `php_flag engine off` to the .htaccess file does not show the source code of the php files, it just displays an internal server error. However, I am concerned that there might be another way to access the source of my files.

- Is there any way to view the source of the php files modifying the .htaccess file if php is running in cgi mode and `php_flag` does not work?
- In case there is some way to view the source, can I fix it or the only option is to use an alternative solution and not exposing the .htaccess file?

Comment: How about `AddType text/plain php`?

Comment: Looks like that could be a problem, I'm going to test it, thanks

Comment: It does not display the code when I add `AddType text/plain php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you have risk exposing the `.htaccess` file to other user which are not in your trust circle although you are using php in cgi mode but I am not sure how capable are other user out there. For example rule like this expose your php code in text.

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler text/plain
</FilesMatch>
```

So what I suggest is don't give full permission to `.htaccess` only give permission to module which are requested or necessary.

For example don't allow modules  such as `mod_mimes`, `indexes` etc to other user.

Don't use

```
AllowOverride All
```

Instead mention module which you want to permit

```
AllowOverride AuthConfig mod_rewrite
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the other user accessing `.htaccess` by changing the file's security policies (Right click, Properties, Security tab). You need to remove the webserver-writable flag from the file, so users will not be able to edit it even using PHP.

Edit: the other option would be using nginx, which does not store configuration files in webroot, so users with webroot specific access can not do anything fishy.

Comment: I do not want to protect the `.htaccess` file itself. I want to protect my php files from a user that can modify the `.htaccess` file.